# Symfony i18n: sync translation keys

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization

For example I have two translation files `notes.en.yml` and `notes.de.yml`.

```
// notes.en.yml
notes:
  info: "Info message"
  critical: "Critical message"


// notes.de.yml
notes:
  info: "Info message"
  critical: "Critical message"
```

How to automatically sync keys of both files if I remove key `notes.info` from `notes.en.yml` only?

It is not hard when I have two files only, but when I will have a few files it is getting complicated.

Comment: I am not sure if any of the frameworks have this, you will have to create some manual script that run on cron or on your execution in order to check all the files according to main on. From my personal experience most of time you keep this files with all data in because you change the code, if you don't have key in cod, you don't show user this data.

Comment: @Alexei I am not sure too =). But I found in the Symfony docs the article http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/translation/debug.html. There's the command `php app/console debug:translation en AcmeDemoBundle`. This command prints missing and unused translations and takes me a list of missing key. So I need to remove this keys.

Comment: The command above can print messages in console only. So I need override this command (or write myself) and out data as php-array. Then I will need to study of removing key in file.yml by keyname. It's seems like decision  but I will need to write some amount of code.

Comment: So in the end you can do a file comparison based on keys, I would solve it with some script running in cron, as I assume you will need it more often cron is better then maul running.